# Sci-Fi novel series - Weapon that kills all universe/dimension versions of a person

Tags: story-identification, novel, hard-sci-fi

I did a few searches and was not able to find something similar.
I am looking for the name(s) of a sci-fi novel series described to me in passing.

The time of discussion was around 2005/2006 in Sydney Australia, I have been informed that there had been several books written already in the series at this stage. Two key elements that I remember the person telling me is about the story has elements of traveling between universes/dimensions, and contains a weapon that is able to destroy not only the person in the current universe/dimension, but all versions of that person in other universes/dimensions.

Unfortunately I have not read the novel. Does anyone have any idea what this may be?

Comment: The Number 1 question here, as a story-id question, will you know the answer when provided, given you never read the series yourself? Would you be able to verify it with your friend who told you about it?

Comment: Hi FuzzyBoots, very valid point. I have asked my friend about it previously (~5 years ago), and he can't recall the name of the novel. This would be a stab in the dark and see what stories people know of that had these two concepts. I can reach out to the friend and clarify once novel names are suggested.

Comment: Reminds me of the destruction of the Earth and everyone from Earth in Douglas Adams' books...

Comment: Sounds a bit like the soul eraser from "the naked god". Each intelligent beign in the universe has a soul, which goes to a separated quantum realm on physical death, a realm by species. A shot from the weapon has the potential of propagating through the realms killing all souls within. Also souls can move through realms, but every individual has a single soul not several.

Comment: I think @DavidW has a point, the book in question sounds like it might be "Mostly Harmless".